# Cause UIScrollView zoomToRect: to only display a portion

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a UIScrollView subclass that contains a UIImageView. When the user double taps on the zone I want to zoom to that CGRect (calculated from CGPoint) and "hide" the rest of the UIImageView. The final effect is similar in Mavel.app and The Walking Dead.app when you are reading a comic.

Until now I got:

```
-(void)presentRect:(CGRect)rect {
  self.bounds = originalFrame;    //1
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"navigateToPos" context:nil];    
  [self zoomToRect:rect animated:NO];
  self.bounds = rect;   
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This works, but "zoomToRect" needs the whole bounds of the UIScrollView and when I restart it (line 1), it gives an undesired effect.

I am stuck with this. I don't know if I need a new approach or need to use another property of UIScrollView.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have a impression they use two black bars upon the uiscrollview, and animate zoom and position. Nothing really hard.

Comment: Hmmm I am not sure, that implies to have 4 bars and calculate Rects for each one according with the visible rect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved using other properies from UIScrollView simulating the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this apps to see it. I'm almost sure they didn't even use uiscrollview. The way the pages moves make me think about that. And uiscrollview should be used only when you really need it, because it have a lot issues when you're customizing. (tiled content, zooming and others problems).

Slide to a next page only 50px aprox., the page goes to the next, in uiscrollview it didn't happen because it works diff.

As I said before, probably it's made using 4 bars (as you correct me) or it can be done with a view wrapping the uiimage and working as a mask. You only need calculate the size of the zoom square and move it to center, and resize the wrapper view to fit this new size. The substitute for the uiscrollview for pages can be a simple image gallery, but where is images you put this "comic-view".

Comment: The behaviour is a little different in iPhone or iPad. In iPad if you move 50px to the right you can see the next image, like a gallery using UIScroolView.